# Refer to a model method within method in Django 1.5

Tags: python, django, templates, methods, model

I have a model

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def field1(self):
        return self.field[10:11]

    def field2(self):
        return self.field1
```

In my template I get the desired result when printing `{{ object.field1 }}`, but it seems I can't refer to another model method within a model method. When printing `{{ object.field2 }}` it fails with message `bound method`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your methods are getters only then it is best to decorate them with `@property`. You won't then need the parentheses when accessing them. Rohan is right, you're missing the parenthesis.

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    @property
    def field1(self):
        return self.field[10:11]

    @property
    def field2(self):
        return self.field1
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `field2()` method you are returning reference to `field1` method, hence template is behaving that way.

You may want to call `field1` from `field2` and then return? Like:

```
def field2(self):
    return self.field1()
```